# Open Neutral, circuit not connected at the panel and too may receptacles on one circuit

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, kitchens, neutral

Beginner here, I am trying to figure out as much as I can before I call in an  electrician.
I have a receptacle in my breakfast area showing open neutral. I turned off the power and checked all other neutral connections. In doing so I discovered several things.

1. My kitchen and breakfast area are on the same circuit(15 amp) as my garage and outdoor receptacles 11 total.
2. Kitchen and breakfast are all 12 gauge wire.  Garage and outdoor are 14 gauge.
3. I have a gfci on my kitchen counter that controls all outlets to the left of it and two to the right.The last one on the right is my problem open neutral. Which today is showing power on one hot and one neutral wire.   Another GFCI in my hallway will shut off all 11 receptacles on the circuit.
4. I have 2 20 amp breakers in my panel labeled kitchen. One controls the fridge and two outlets. We couldn’t figure out the other one until today. When I took the cover off I realized that there are no wires going to 17-kitchen. Inside the panel there is a black hot and a white neutral that are not connected to anything. My guess would be that is my 20 amp kitchen connection.
5. Before connecting this should I switch all the outlets on this circuit to 20 amp? How can I find where they are tied to now, somewhere on the 15 amp circuit? I would love for them to be separate circuits. This would also eliminate the tripping
   Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. This question covers a lot of ground and is likely to be closed as it [needs more focus](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (see para. 3). Please feel free to [edit] your question to address one thing at a time. 1) Too many outlets on a circuit (your Q1). 2) Different gauge wiring on the same circuit (depends on the breaker in the panel). 3) multiple GFCI outlets, etc. You can ask the questions all at once, or ask the first and let it inform and shape the next question as you learn.

Comment: Those wires in your panel did not spontaneously disconnect themselves. And since presumably your kitchen outlets are currently working - so they're not relying on that cable. Don't reconnect it until you know where it actually goes and why it's disconnected now.

Comment: Where in the world are you? Residential in the us doesn't have a max only commercial and industrial, are back stabs in use? Don’t start moving things around until you know what is going on. Is the receptacle not working or you just testing?

Comment: Those plug-in 3-light detectors are only reliable for "correct" and "open ground".  All other indications are wrong and misleading.  That's because they are designed for wiring *mistakes* in *brand new wiring*, and definitely not for the more complex task of finding wiring *failures* in old wiring (which was correct when installed).

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The kitchen outlets work with the exception of the one testing open neutral.  No power but voltage tester lights up on one of the neutral wires. 
All 11 receptacles are controlled by a 15 amp circuit at the breaker box. 
I now understand why we seem to trip the circuit quite a bit ‍♀️
I am assuming the two loose wires were never connected in the panel. Even though that breaker is labeled kitchen 20 amp and the wires are 12 gauge.I guess a call to a professional is in order. I would really like to have my kitchen on the empty 20 amp circuit.

Comment: Be sure to take a lot of pictures and notes before you change anything.